# How to use class custom initializer with coordinator in swift

Tags: swift, initialization

I have to work on a project which is using coordinator for presenting new controllers which I can copy & paste it to continue coding like that.

But when I create a new class with a custom initializer I can't present it with coordinator.

A regular class can be presented like this:

```
let vc = DatePickerViewController.instantiateFromStoryboardName(storyboardName: .GlobalStoryboard)
        Coordinator.presentViewController(sourceViewController: self, destinationViewController: vc)
```

But how can I fill the custom initializer values for the `destinationViewController`?

Comment: Assign the coordinator to a property of the new view controller before presenting it, `vc.coordinator = coordinator`

Comment: I'm doing that already but I want to use dependency injection which is not what I'm doing now!

Comment: Dependency injection isn't limited to using init methods so this will work too.

Comment: I want to use something that force me to initialize the class to prevent some troubles in future.

Comment: You can't really, your DatePickerViewController will always have other init methods available.